# Batch or VBS: Running a console program

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, console

I like to run a console programm (like *fsutil* or *ln*) to find all *hardware siblings within a folder* and log all results in a textfile.
It is easy to do this when the names in the folder are known like

- fsutil hardlink list "83333 Curriculum vitae.jpg" >
  hardwarelinks2.txt
- fsutil hardlink list "77127 Prolis Moderatio.jpg" >>
  hardwarelinks2.txt

and so on ... ,
but how when the number of files is too big and the filenames in the folder are unknown.
I tried this in VBS but it always bring some errors

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "J:\Test"
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile in colFiles
 oShell.run "cmd.exe /c fsutil hardlink list """ & objFile.Name & """ >> hw2.txt"
Next
Set oShell = Nothing
```

Seems to be some problems with blank spaces in the filenames, so I must use QUOTATION MARKS - but how to do it?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

To be used inside a batch file

```dos
(for %%a in ("j:\test\*") do @fsutil hardlink list "%%a") > hardlinks2.txt
```

Or if you want to execute it from vbs

```
oShell.run "cmd /q /c ""(for %a in (""j:\test\*"") do fsutil hardlink list ""%a"") > hardlinks2.txt"""
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the Batch is working, _the VBscript not..._

Comment: @Gurkenhobel, sorry, my fault. I forget the closing quotes. Updated.